# OpenID login in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

Im newbie in C#, I have been asked to implement the OpenID login with provided username and password and get the bearer token.

We achieved this in Java code snipped is as below.(don't know how do same in C#)

```
public AccessTokenResponse getToken() throws IOException, ParseException, Exception {

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("");
        ClientCredentialsGrant clientAuth = new ClientCredentialsGrant();
        Map<String, String> parameters = clientAuth.toParameters();
        for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
            query.append(key).append("=").append(parameters.get(key)).append("&");
        }

        ClientID clientID = new ClientID(config.getProperty(ConfigConstants.USERNAME));

        Secret secret = new Secret(config.getPassword());

        ClientSecretBasic csb = new ClientSecretBasic(clientID, secret);

        //logger.info("URL:" + this.getOpenIDMetadata(config.getProperty(ConfigConstants.DOMAIN)).getTokenEndpointURI().toString());

        TokenRequest tokenRequest = new TokenRequest(this.getOpenIDMetadata(config.getProperty(ConfigConstants.DOMAIN)).getTokenEndpointURI(), csb, clientAuth);
        HTTPRequest request = tokenRequest.toHTTPRequest();

        HTTPResponse httpResponse = request.send();

        accessToken = AccessTokenResponse.parse(httpResponse);

    return accessToken;
}
```

We have a server which is an openid provider and this is how get the **OIDCProviderMetadata**

```
private OIDCProviderMetadata getOpenIDMetadata(String domain) throws Exception {
    if (this.metadata == null) {
        String confURL = this.serverURL+ config.getIDP() + domain + "/authn/.well-known/openid-configuration";

        HTTPRequest configRequest = new HTTPRequest(HTTPRequest.Method.GET, new URL(confURL));
        HTTPResponse configResponse = configRequest.send();
        metadata = OIDCProviderMetadata.parse(configResponse.getContent());
    }
    return metadata;
}
```

Question is how to implement same thing in C#?

I did some research around this, found there is/are official OpendID implementation in C# i.e.
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2

but did not find any samples which will help me to implement likewise in Java implementation i have. All examples demonstrate do openid login in browser or mobiles devices i don't want that, I want similar implementation as we have in Java(above).

Any help would be appreciated or code snipped would be more helpful.

Comment: These samples should provide good guidance: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

Comment: how to get OIDCProviderMetadata object in C#?

Comment: Given that that is a Java object... I'm going with you aren't going to. Not sure what the equivalent in C# would be